# Iterate through a table to find matches in data object

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I want to itterate throug an `HTML Collection` of table rows and match certain `td` text value to a value in `data array of objects` I recieve from server.
Is there a way to make it more efficient, cuz with 89 data objects and 31 rows I get too many itterations with usual for loops

here is what I was trying:

```
let dataArray;
let tableRows = table.tBodies[0].rows;

for (row of tableRows) {
  let val1 = row.cells[2].textContent;

  for (elem of dataArray) {
    let val2 = elem.c[3].v
    if (val1 === val2) {
     console.log(true)
  }
}
}
```

Comment: 89 * 31 is 2759 iterations altogether  - that alone should not create any serious issues, especially if what you are doing in each iteration, is so minimal. But if you extracted all those `elem.c[3].v` values into a flat array _once_ beforehand, then you could use [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if your current cell value is contained in that array in one go, and without _explicitly_ looping over dataArray again and again yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Still find it difficult to see if my solution is good enough

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `Set`, add all texts you are to search for to the set and then loop `dataArray` and see whether the set has them. I made slight changes on your data references for the sake of brevity.

```js
let dataArray = [
    {
        c: ['a', 'b', 'c', '10']
    },
    {
        c: ['a', 'b', 'c', '15']
    },
    {
        c: ['a', 'b', 'c', '-1']
    },
    {
        c: ['a', 'b', 'c', '4']
    },
    {
        c: ['a', 'b', 'c', '3']
    },
];
let tableRows = document.querySelector('table').tBodies[0].rows;
let s = new Set();

for (row of tableRows) {
    s.add(row.querySelector("td").textContent);
}


for (elem of dataArray) {
  let val2 = elem.c[3];
  if (s.has(val2)) {
    console.log(val2)
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>4</td></tr>
        <tr><td>5</td></tr>
        <tr><td>6</td></tr>
        <tr><td>7</td></tr>
        <tr><td>8</td></tr>
        <tr><td>9</td></tr>
        <tr><td>10</td></tr>
        <tr><td>11</td></tr>
        <tr><td>12</td></tr>
        <tr><td>13</td></tr>
        <tr><td>14</td></tr>
        <tr><td>15</td></tr>
        <tr><td>16</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```